# How to add a permanent placeholder in a UItextfield for swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to allow a textfield to always have "@gmail.com" at the end when the user starts typing. So after any changes to the textfield it will always have that line attached to whatever the user has already typed and the user should not be able to delete it.

I have tried using "shouldChangeCharactersIn" function but can't seem to make it work.

The reason why I am doing this is so the user can understand that we only will accept gmail accounts and thought it would be the best way instead of trying to parse out the last 10 characters of the string to check for "@gmail.com".

Comment: IMHO, the textfield should hold the part that the user can edit.  I'd suggest placing a label after the textfield that contains the `@gmail.com` part.

Comment: @vacawama, just what I answered. Very good thought hehe.

Comment: I would @vacawama but I want it inside the textbox and dynamically adjust as the user types

Comment: Did u try the textfield’s ‘rightView’ property? Set it as a label with the text “@gmail”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this instead:

[image]

And have a control if the user adds `@` then reject that part:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField.tag == 0 {
        if string == "@" {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

So you basically show the label that it´s `@gmail.com` and the user adds the first part in the `textField`.

**Update:**
And if you really want it inside the textField use this:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.text = textField.text! + "@gmail.com"

        textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.beginningOfDocument)
    }
```

Two parts here:
1: `textField.text = textField.text! + "@gmail.com"` - adds @gmail.com to your string
2: `textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.beginningOfDocument)` - places the cursor in the beginning when the user taps the textField.

Comment: I wanted to have the '@gmail.com' inside the text box and as the user types it would dynamically adjust with the text.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for but is there a way for the user to not be able to delete the "@gmail.com"?